# PushKit Framework crashing

Tags: ios, xcode, pushkit

I am trying to use ios pushkit . I have imported the framework to my project and add the code for registry to receive push notification, but my problem is that my app crashing when i try to open and i getting 
`Dyld Message: no cache image with name (@rpath/PushKit.framework/PushKit)`  error in my crash log.
what is the reason of the crashing.

Comment: Are you testing on a iOS version lower than iOS8?

Comment: thanks for replaying Larme.no i testing on ios 9.2.1.